# Deadbolt will not unlock from inside if locked with key from outside and vice versa

Tags: doors, lock, deadbolt

Our office door deadbolt will only unlock with a key if locked with a key.  If you lock it with the key from outside and then someone tries to unlock the deadbolt from inside with the knob, it won't unlock.  Same with locking it with the knob inside - you can't unlock with the key from the outside.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Get a new deadbolt lock. This setup sounds like it was designed that way.

Comment: If it has always been that way, get a new lock as this is incredibly unsafe - it could lead to someone locked inside during a fire. If it has *not* always been that way, what brand is the lock. Ideally, model # but locks usually don't show a model # externally. Pictures may help.

Comment: Depending on where you are, fire regulations may require exit hardware, like a push door latch, that won't require any unlocking to exit your office. Switching out that broken deadbolt for fire door hardware would be safer even if not required.

Comment: @Triplefault but fire doors are extremely expensive last I checked. Those panic push bars are like a thousand bucks each.

Comment: @Nelson, could be true, haven't priced them myself. Code rules, though, where it rules, and being able to easily get out of a burning room and live is priceless.

Comment: Just searched "panic bar" push exit door hardware, Home Depot has them for high $tens to low $hundreds. NJ USA

Comment: It might have been assembled with something spun wrong inside. Disassemble and rebuild…

Comment: Having worked on locks for years, I agree with @Aloysius that there is something wrong with the lock and it might be a simple fix (disassembly and reassembly). However, i also like the recommendations to check your local codes for types of door hardware required.